# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value was not an array [java.util.ArrayList]

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I am trying to save the `List<byte[]>` object in Postgres DB, but I am getting the below error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value was not an array [java.util.ArrayList]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.ArrayMutabilityPlan.deepCopyNotNull(ArrayMutabilityPlan.java:23) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.MutableMutabilityPlan.deepCopy(MutableMutabilityPlan.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.deepCopy(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:308) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.deepCopy(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:304) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.deepCopy(TypeHelper.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:279) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:135) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:710) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:696) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:314) ~[spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:554) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:371) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:204) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:657) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:621) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

Pojo

```
public class InvoiceImages implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final int MAX_IMAGE_SIZE = 40 * 1000 * 1024; // 40 MB
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "hibernate_sequence")
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.BinaryType")
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Column(name = "image", length =  MAX_IMAGE_SIZE)
    private List<byte[]> image;
    
    @Column(name = "invoice_id")
    private Long invoiceId;
}
```

MainApp

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ByteaDemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ByteaDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private InvoiceImagesRepository repo;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        List<byte[]> bytes = new ArrayList<>();
        bytes.add("kk".getBytes());
        bytes.add("bb".getBytes());
        
        repo.save(InvoiceImages.builder().invoiceId(1L).image(bytes).build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

List cannot be deepCopy?

change your List to byte[]

try this

```
@Column(name="image")
@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.BinaryType")
private byte[] image;
```

Comment: Thanks, I dont see a way to have a single image object when I am getting more than one?

Comment: It's best to store it on DFS，The database stores only URLs

Comment: Sorry I am not clear, can you show some working examples please?

Comment: my English is poor.
you can upload your images to your image-server and save,then you can get some addresses for your images, you can save them use `String` split with `,`.
just like `/opt/image/1.jpg,/opt/image/2.jpg`
you can use nginx reverse proxy your image-server to get a domain name
like 'www.google.com'
your image-url just like `www.google.com/opt/image/1.jpg`